# How to apply any style to FullCalendar cells

Tags: fullcalendar

great people from Stack!

I'm having some issues working with Full Calendar I would like to get some help with.

First of all, Full Calendar is an amazing tool. Everything I have had any doubt with has been solved in a breeze just by taking a look at the docs or googling five minutes. However, there is a problem I'm dealing with and can't find (I'm starting to suspect it is virtually impossible, or at least it is for me to imagine how to do it) the way to get it solved.

I'm implementing this library in a project which is meant to be something like an appointments manager, among other things. A (simple) functionality I wanted to add is to open a modal when a calendar cell (agenda week would be the main view) is clicked with a form, allowing to create an appointment for the selected cell. To improve usability, I thought it would be nice if the cells had some kind of hover effect, so that you can feel there is 'something' behind clicking this element. The thing is, the calendar is composed by something like 2 separated overlapping tables, one with rows and the other with columns, that form the grid. The modal system is done and working, dayClick made the trick. Any way to do anything similar to what I am talking about, the hover stuff? (my idea was to make some kind of (+) button appear when hovering, but anything would work.

Thank you!
Seth

Edit: I noticed there is a 'selectable' directive which, given only to the AgendaWeek view, allows me to select cells. The selection is made by the JS code, adding an element just above the cell, with its dimensions. Wouldn't it be any way to call this from hovering a cell instead of just clicking it? I wonder that highlight cell is rendered from the position of the mouse at the time of the click and wouldn't be very efficient to check that all the time...

Comment: what have you tried so far? The cells have CSS classes, can't you hang something off that?

Comment: Cells have classes but as it isn't a single table with its own cells but 2 overlapping cells, one holding rows and the other columns, I can't point to a single cell by HTML as they don't exist as cells. Sry for my poor English btw.

Comment: couldn't you just put the hover rule on the whole grid then? Unless you have some rules by which not all of it is selectable?

Comment: Well, the thing is, I would like only the hovered cell to be highlighted, not the whole calendar grid :P
Added something I noticed to the question above, I don't know if it's useful.

Comment: "there is a 'selectable' directive which, given only to the AgendaWeek view"...no it works on the Month and agendaDay views as well (see https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/selectable.html), it only doesn't work on the List views (because there's no time-dependent grid on which to make a selection)

Comment: "Wouldn't it be any way to call this from hovering a cell instead of just clicking it"...possibly if you alter the fullCalendar source code to make it respond to a hover instead of a click, you'd have to look and see. But bearing in mind the user can select multiple cells at once, how would you know when the user wanted to begin and end selecting and wanted to create an event of that size (as opposed to simply moving their mouse around the screen)? It would be a _very_ unusual user experience, and difficult to control. Dragging and dropping is much more normal for users and easier to implement

Comment: Yeah, been thinking about that and reached the same answer. Guess I'll have to live without that feature, still a tiny concession for a tool like FC, so gotta think about anything similar. Thank you @ADyson!

P.D: in the previous comment I didn't meant it *only* worked there; I expressed myself incorrectly. The thing is, as I am mainly working with that view, I referred exclusively to it, but not meaning the other views were unable to hold the 'selectable' directive.